# ¿Cómo conseguir el nombre de un archivo usando HTML Form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tal y como dice el titulo, estoy buscando una forma de conseguir el nombre de un archivo usando `HTML` `form` y `php`.

El código del formulario `HTML` es el siguiente:

```
<form method="post" action="../api/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
    <legend>Ingresar un Alumno</legend>
    <label for="img">Foto Alumno:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Y el código que tengo para recibir el archivo como variable es `PHP`:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $nombre_foto = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
```

Obviamente los códigos son mucho más grandes puesto que tengo otros datos.

Ahora, probé con `$_FILES` tal como se ve en el código, pero me arroja un error de `"undefined variable"`, también probé con un simple `filter input`, pero al revisar la base de datos, no guarda nada y queda en blanco. Probé usando tanto `VARCHAR` como `LONGBLOB` para esto.

Lo que quiero es simplemente guardar el nombre del archivo, nada más que eso. ¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo o es imposible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes utilizar la mezcla de opendir y readdir o scandir o glob.

***Nota:*** Supongo que ya conoces el directorio base y que el archivo es variable.

Entonces, el código a usar es:

```
$directorio_base = __DIR__ ;

$dir_handle = opendir($directorio_base);

while(($archivo = readdir($dir_handle)) !== false) {
  $ruta = $directorio_base . '/' . $archivo;
  echo $ruta . PHP_EOL;
  if(is_file($ruta)) {
      $ext = pathinfo($ruta, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   }
}
closedir($dir_handle);
```

Con glob

```
$directorio_base = __DIR__ ;

$archivos = glob($directorio_base . '/*.xlsx');

foreach($archivos as $archivo) {
    //trabajar con cada archivo
}
```

Si tu directorio es otra ruta al directorio base, puedes usar `$directorio_base = "../"` si es un directorio superior, si es uno inferior, la ruta relativa `$directorio_base = "/otro_dir/"`

Si deseas subir a más directorios superiores puedes usar los `"../../../"` cuantas veces requieras.

Suerte!

Comment: ¿Ese codigo lo pongo cuando declaro las variables? 

Porque tengo entendido que DIR usa el directorio actual, pero la carpeta donde esta almacenada la imagen no es la misma donde esta almacenado el codigo

Comment: He editado la respuesta

Comment: Sirvio !!!!!!!
Ooooh gracias compadre, me salvaste, te lo agradezco

Comment: Para eso estamos!